# How to download a minecraft.jar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tryed to download the Tale of Two Kingdoms mod for Minecraft. I opened up the bin and there was no minecraft.jar! How do I download minecraft.jar so I can download Tale of Two Kingdoms?

Comment: I want to say this is a duplicate... I swear I've seen this before

Comment: I want to know how to get the minecraft.jar in the .minecraft foler under bin!

Comment: which version of Minecraft are you running? do you see a "Versions" Folder? what version does the mod say it's for? i am getting the feeling your using trying to install an old mod in a new version of minecraft (which doesn't have a [bin folder](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/.minecraft)) and the instructions you are using are outdated

Comment: @Ben yeh i got that feeling to but i can't find it, possible that it's been deleted because it was downvoted and marked as duplicate of a "how do i mod the newer minecraft" like question

Comment: Why does this feel like a Linux thing more than a Windows thing?

Comment: The Version is 1.8.1, and the mod is tale of two kingdoms!

Comment: I feel a little suspicious that this is a question on how to almost in a way "pirate" Minecraft. Anyone agree?

Answer (score 0):

There Should be a "jar" button click it and it would either say Run or Link will be at the bottom of the screen and click it and it should download.

Comment: Could you explain this more as to where this button is (like a screenshot). to my knolwedge the launcher has no such button that *"would either say Run or Link will be at the bottom of the screen"*

Comment: what? i dont understand!